# Crear un bucle en JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mediante un *input*, quería crear las capas que en este se indican, creando un *for* en una función, pero el bucle no se para y crea infinitos *div*. Lo siguiente es el código del input:

```
        <input type="number" id="numeroCapas"><button onclick="addCapaInput()">Añadir capas anteriores</button></br>
```

Aquí dejo el código de la función:

```
function addCapaInput(){
var x = document.getElementById("numeroCapas").value;
for (x in numeroCapas){
    var caja = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('section').appendChild(caja);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `numeroCapas`?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta

Comment: En tu _for in_ tienes `for(x in numeroCapas)`, donde `numeroCapas` debe ser una variable ¿qué valor contiene dicha variable?

Comment: Yo quiero que en el *input* se introduzca un número, por ejemplo el 3. Tras eso que se impriman 3 cajas en pantalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda la estructura de un *for...in*, este **requiere** de un objeto, por lo que si el "iterable" no es un objeto, el bucle nunca se va a parar

[Documentación en MDN de for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

En este caso, puedes usar un `for` "tradicional", haciendo uso de [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para poder convertir un string a un entero

> **IMPORTANTE:** Strings no convertibles a enteros darán [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

```js
function addCapaInput() {
  if (isNaN(parseInt(numeroCapas.value))) {
    alert("Número no válido");
  } else {
    for(let i = 1; i <= parseInt(numeroCapas.value); i++) {
      const el = document.createElement("div");
      el.innerHTML = "Div "+i;
      section.appendChild(el);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numeroCapas"><button onclick="addCapaInput()">Añadir capas anteriores</button><br/>
<div id="section"></div>
```

Haremos uso de [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) para comprobar que el string si sea convertible a un entero, si no es convertible enviaremos una alerta

Si lo es, procederemos a iniciar el bucle, contando desde 1 hasta el número introducido y poniendo nuevos `<div>` por cada número que recorra el bucle